# Issue while loading an avro dataset into Teradata with spark-streaming

Tags: apache-spark, teradata, spark-avro, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to load a dataset of avro files into a Teradata table through spark streaming (jdbc). The configuration is properly set and the load succeeds to certain extent (I can validate rows of data have been inserted into the table), but halfways through I start having exceptions and the load fails. The stacktrace is below. Any inkling as to what might causing this ?

```
18/02/08 17:27:42 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 16.20.00.02] [Error 1154] [SQLState HY000] A failure occurred while inserting the batch of rows destined for database table "database"."table". Details of the failure can be found in the exception chain that is accessible with getNextException.
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeBatchUpdateException(ErrorFactory.java:149)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeBatchUpdateException(ErrorFactory.java:133)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.fastload.FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.executeBatch(FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.java:2389)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$.savePartition(JdbcUtils.scala:592)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$saveTable$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:670)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$saveTable$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:670)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreachPartition$1$$anonfun$apply$29.apply(RDD.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1951)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1951)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 16.20.00.02] [Error 1147] [SQLState HY000] The next failure(s) in the exception chain occurred while beginning FastLoad of database table "database"."table"
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:95)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDriverJDBCException(ErrorFactory.java:70)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.fastload.FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.beginFastLoad(FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.java:966)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc.fastload.FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.executeBatch(FastLoadManagerPreparedStatement.java:2210)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue stems from trying to load data in append mode to an existing table. FAST LOAD doesn't support that. The table should be empty (a.k.a truncated) each time the process runs. Which makes this useful for staging data prior to crunching it. But not for storing it.